# Cannot resolve method FAB.show();

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I was trying to make and android app with two fragments in a `ViewPager` together tabs, fine up to there.

The problem came when I added a `FloatingActionButtom` and I wanted it to change depending on the tab in which you are in. This is what I have:

With this the icon changes when the pages are changed but I want it to do it with [this animation](https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0B6Okdz75tqQsRTUzS2ZHaVRQaDg/components-buttons-fab-behavior_04_xhdpi_009.mp4) and to do that I need to call `fab.hide();` and `fab.show();` but Android studio sais this methods dont exist, so what can I do?

I have all my SDKs up to date together with the IDE and have included the latest design-support library on my gradle: `compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'`, also Ive imported `android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;` into my MainActivity.
I also tried to write it on another computer (just in case) and nothing, the cannot resolve method error keeps poping up.

```
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
FloatingActionButton fab;
ActionBar actionBar;
ContadorFragment fragContador;
Context context;

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fabAñadir);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);

    context = this;

    fragContador = new ContadorFragment();

    setupViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);


    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if (position == 0){ //Esta en el contado
                fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_save_black_24dp);
                verEstadisticas = false;
            } else{// esta en las estadisticas
                verEstadisticas = true;
                fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_add_black_24dp);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }
    });
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    adapter.addFrag(fragContador, "Contador");
    adapter.addFrag(new EstadisticasFragment(), "Estadisticas");

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

And the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
app:layout_behavior="com.app.common.PatchedScrollingViewBehavior"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="exitUntilCollapsed"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="#000000"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabAñadir"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        fab:fab_type="normal"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The latest is actually `com.android.support:design:23.1.0`

Comment: Does it work for an android 5.1.1 app?

Comment: @cricket_007 that seems to be for android 6 or not?

Comment: Haven't tried, I was just saying that is the latest, not the version you specified

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks anyway, i will try it

Comment: Also, those should be methods, according [to the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html). Are you sure `fab instanceof FloatingActionButton`?

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes Im 100% sure of that, thats why it looks so weird...

Comment: Can you add more of your code? Like how `fab` is initialized? I've just imported it myself, and I have show and hide as methods

Comment: @cricket_007 Ive updated the code code, also thanks for your time :)

Comment: And your `activity_main.xml`, please?

Comment: @cricket_007 There it is :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the [Support Library release notes here](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html#revisions). The show() and hide() methods for the floating action button were added in revision 22.2.1, but you're using 22.2.0. Update to a newer version, preferably the latest(currently 23.1.1) and it will work.

Comment: Good find. Didn't think about checking there.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm really not sure what to tell you, but I got a running example in a brand new project.

**Gradle**

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="exitUntilCollapsed"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="#000000"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Toggle FAB"
                android:id="@+id/btn_toggle_fab"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            fab:fab_type="normal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FloatingActionButton fab;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "FAB clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.btn_toggle_fab).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (fab.isShown()) {
                    fab.hide();
                } else {
                    fab.show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I finally fixed it.